# Referencing Workbook - Not working for coworker

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm using the following code to open up a workbook in the same folder as the current file given a file name entered into a cell. Everything is working for me, but when my coworker runs it, he gets a subscript out of range error for Workbooks(modFile). I verified that he has macros enabled. I also tried running it with the file extension added to the modFile string and it didn't work. Does anyone know why it could be working for me (and other coworkers) and not him and what I can do to fix it.

```
pathName = ActiveWorkbook.Path
current = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5)
modFileName = Sheets("Main").Range("B1").Value
modFile = Left(modFileName, Len(modFileName) - 5)
modFileAddress = pathName & "\" & modFileName

modFileExists = Dir(modFileAddress)

If modFileExists = "" Then
    MsgBox "Module Tracking File Not Found. Verify Name."
End If

ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:=modFileAddress
If (Workbooks(modFile).Sheets("Master").AutoFilterMode And Workbooks(modFile).Sheets("Master").FilterMode) Or Workbooks(modFile).Sheets("Master").FilterMode Then
    Workbooks(modFile).Sheets("Master").ShowAllData
End If
Workbooks(modFile).Sheets("Master").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="80"
Workbooks(modFile).Sheets("Master").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:="0"
lastrow = Workbooks(modFile).Sheets("Master").Cells(Workbooks(modFile).Sheets("Master").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Workbooks(current).Sheets("Master Data").Cells.Clear
Workbooks(modFile).Sheets("Master").Range("A1:AE" & lastrow).Copy Workbooks(current).Sheets("Master Data").Range("A1")
Workbooks(modFileName).Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Private Sub is located in Sheet1 triggered by a button click. I also verified that my coworker is putting the file name in the correct cell and it is longer than 5 characters.

Comment: Much better: `Dim wb As Workbook`, `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=modFileAddress)`, then replace all instances of `Workbooks(modFile)` with `wb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Filtered Range to Another Workbook

- It is assumed that the worksheets `"Main"` and `"Master Data"` are located in the `Destination Workbook` i.e. the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`), while the worksheet `"Master"` is located in the to be opened `Source Workbook`.
- Not tested.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Workbook.
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Open and create a reference to the Source Workbook.
    
    Dim swbName As String: swbName = dwb.Worksheets("Main").Range("B1").Value
    Dim swbPath As String: swbPath = dwb.Path & "\" & swbName
    
    If Dir(swbPath) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Module Tracking File Not Found. Verify Name."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=swbPath)
    
    ' Filter the Source Worksheet.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Master")
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then
        sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    Dim sLastR As Long: sLastR = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    sws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="80"
    sws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:="0"
    
    ' Copy the filtered data from Source to Destination Worksheet.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("Master Data")
    dws.Cells.Clear
    sws.Range("A1:AE" & sLastR).Copy dws.Range("A1")
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    'dwb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue here with how you are referencing your opened workbook. Each time you use `Workbooks(modFile)` you are searching for an index string in the list of open workbooks. If you search for that string in a list that doesn't contain that string, eg. it hasn't fully opened yet, it will throw an index out of bounds error. Do what BigBen said and replace all instances of `Workbooks(modFile` with a reference to a workbook variable.

```
dim wb as Workbook
set wb = Workbooks.Open("file\path\here...")
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```